# Retain my own classes?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How do I retain classes that I write?

Comment: What do you mean by 'retain'?

Comment: classes don't have to be retained, they are all singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 'retain' has a very specific meaning in Cocoa applications. It is used in pair with 'release' to augment the internal reference counter of an instance of NSObject (i.e. any class that inherits from NSObject). As such, one does not retain a class, but rather one retains an instance of that class. This is done as such:

```
Person *person = [[[Person alloc] init] autorelease];
[person retain];
```

For more information see:

http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#retain

Answer (score 0):

retain and release are implemented in NSObject so you don't have to do anything for the release count mechanism to work with your custom classes.  But maybe you could be more specific about your question ?